# R: Count how many times value has occured before within certain range of rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame("subj.no" = rep(1:3, each = 24), 
                 "trial.no" = rep(1:3, each = 8, length.out = 72), 
                 "item" = c(rep(c("ball", "book"), 4), rep(c("doll", "rope"), 4), rep(c("fish", "box"), 4), rep(c("paper", "candle"), 4), rep(c("horse", "marble"), 4), rep(c("doll", "rope"), 4), rep(c("tree", "dog"), 4), rep(c("ball", "book"), 4), rep(c("horse", "marble"), 4)),
                 "rep.no" = rep(1:4, each = 2, length.out = 72),
                 "DV" = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,
                      1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0),)
```

I now want to create another column `DV.no` which says that the value `1` occurred the nth time within that combination of `subj.no`, `trial.no` and `item`. For `DV==0`, the value in the new column should be 0.

So the resulting vector should look like this:

```
DV.no = c(1,0,2,0,3,0,0,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,3,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,3,1,1,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,0,2,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,3,1,0)
```

So basically, for each unique combination of values in `subj.no`, `trial.no` and `item`, whenever the value of `DV` is 1, then 1 should be added to the count in the new variable.

(Remark: The column `rep.no` is not part of the relevant value combination. But it's in the df anyway, and since I didn't know if it's useful for the solution, I left it there.)

How can this be done in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by `cumsum` on the 'DV' column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(subj.no, trial.no, item) %>% 
     mutate(V.no = cumsum(DV)* DV)
```

---

Or in `base R` with `ave`

```
df$V.no <- with(df, DV *ave(DV, subj.no, trial.no, item, FUN = cumsum))
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick response! But sum is not quite what I need. Instead of giving the same sum every time for that combination I want a count for that specific row the "how many-th" time the 1 appeared. So the value will get higher for every new 1 in that specific combination.