# Detect a change in values in a vector

Tags: r, grouping

This is related to my question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224258/r-count-how-many-times-value-has-occured-before-within-certain-range-of-rows) but in a way needs the opposite output.
I have the same dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("subj.no" = rep(1:3, each = 24), 
                 "trial.no" = rep(1:3, each = 8, length.out = 72), 
                 "item" = c(rep(c("ball", "book"), 4), rep(c("doll", "rope"), 4), rep(c("fish", "box"), 4), rep(c("paper", "candle"), 4), rep(c("horse", "marble"), 4), rep(c("doll", "rope"), 4), rep(c("tree", "dog"), 4), rep(c("ball", "book"), 4), rep(c("horse", "marble"), 4)),
                 "rep.no" = rep(1:4, each = 2, length.out = 72),
                 "DV" = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,
                      1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0),)
```

I now want to create a column where 1 is entered in every row with `DV == 0` iff there is a lower rep.no **of the same subj.no-trial.no-item group** with `DV == 1`. 0 should be entered in all other rows.

How can this be done? I assume, like in my last post, `df %>% group_by(subj.no, trial.no, item)` is the first step. But I am stuck at the conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr
df %>% 
  group_by(subj.no, trial.no, item) %>% 
  mutate(min_rep_no = min(rep.no[DV == 1]),
         new_col = if_else(DV == 0 & rep.no > min_rep_no, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Almost. Your piece of code disregarded the item variable in the grouping. I added it and got the result that I wanted. But I got a warning: "In min(rep.no[DV == 1]) : "no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"". Hope that is not a problem.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot that. I think the warning means that there is no rep.no with DV ==1, so the `min` function returns `Inf`, which guarantees that there will be no lower rep.no if there is no rep.no where DV ==1

Comment: Ah, yes, that's exactly it. Then it won't cause any problems to new_col. Thanks for your help!